# How to detect if a userform control is losing focus / being exited by a mouseclick vs tabbing

Tags: excel, vba

**Background**

I have a userform with multipages, a textbox and a commandbutton. Each multipage also has a number of textboxes. I want to be able to move by tabbing (forwards and backwards) from the last textbox on the first page to the first textbox on the second page, ect., ... , and from the last textbox on the last page to the textbox below the multipage.

I thought I had created a solution for this (shown below); however, my solution does not allow the tabbing order to be interrupted by the user (mouse)clicking on either the non-next tab or the textbox below the multipage object. Instead they have to tab the entire way through the multipage object, which may involve quite a lot of unnecessary tabbing.

**Attempts**

I intially tried to reset the global var `tabDirect` to `NonTab` at the end of every `Multipage_Exit` run. The result was that the first click (to either a different page or outside the multipage object) was treated as a tab, while the second was actually treated as a mouseclick.

I also attempted changing `tabDirect` to `NonTab` in every mouseclick event in the userform. However, the mouseclick event for a control outside the current page never happened.

After researching, it looks as though when a mouseclick occurs on the textbox below the multipage the events are:

1. Leaves multipage
2. Enter Textbox
3. TextBox_MouseDown

Is there another event after the MouseDown event? Or another way to tell if the mouse is clicked or what keys are pressed during an exit event?

**Notes**

I am aware of another suggestion to accomplish the tabbing through pages by inserting a commandbutton, which when tabbed to, would "flip the page", so to speak, to the next page in the multipage object. I was hoping for a cleaner-looking route; hence the code in the `multipage_exit` sub.

I am also fully aware that the answer to my question may end up being "not possible". However, people sometimes come up with amazing solutions to difficult problems, and I guess I'm hoping that this will be one of those times.

That said, I am also open to other suggestions/recommendations for tabbing through the pages of a multipage object.

**Intial Code**

Global Variable(s)

```
Public tabDirect As tabbing

Public Enum tabbing
    [_First] = 1
    NonTab = 1
    Forwards
    Backwards
    [_Last] = 3
End Enum
```

Userform Sub

```
Private Sub Multipage_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim cnt As Integer

    If tabDirect <> NonTab Then 'If not tabbing, skip to end of sub
        ' determines value of next page
        If tabDirect = Backwards Then
            counter = Multipage.Value - 1
        ElseIf tabDirect = Forwards Then
            counter = Multipage.Value + 1
        End If

        'If tabbing backwards while on the first page,
        'the counter would have a value of -1 here
        If counter < 0 Then '
            counter = Multipage.Pages.Count - 1
        End If

        'Only way for counter to equal Multipage.Pages.Count,
        'is if tabbing forward off of last page.
        'Desired result is to leave the multipage
        If counter <> Multipage.Pages.Count Then
            'Tabbing forwards: want first textbox, tabbing backwards: want last
            If tabDirect = Backwards Then
                cnt = Multipage.Pages(counter).Controls.Count - 2 ' skip over label
            Else
                cnt = 0
            End If

            Multipage.Value = counter

            With Multipage.Pages(counter).Controls(cnt)
                .SetFocus
                .SelStart = 0
                .SelLength = Len(.Value)
            End With

            'Fixing scollbar
            If tabDirect = Backwards Then
                Multipage.Pages(counter).ScrollTop = Multipage.Pages(counter).ScrollHeight
            Else
                Multipage.Pages(counter).ScrollTop = 0
            End If

            'Don't want to cancel when leaving first page backwards
            If tabDirect <> Backwards Or counter <> Multipage.Pages.Count - 1 Then
                Cancel = True
            End If
        Else
            Multipage.Value = 0
            Multipage.Pages(0).ScrollTop = 0
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Code in textbox class for each textbox on form

```
Private Sub Textbox_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    'KeyCode 9 = tab
    If KeyCode = 9 And Shift = 1 Then
        tabDirect = Backwards
    ElseIf KeyCode = 9 Then
        tabDirect = Forwards
    Else
        tabDirect = NonTab
    End If
End Sub
```

Code in each control's MouseDown event on userform

```
Private Sub Control_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    tabDirect = NonTab
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I was unable to find a way to differentiate between tabbing and mouseclicking, I did find another way to determine if the multipage was being exited other than tabbing to the next textbox.

I worked with the assumption that if a multipage exit event got triggered by tabbing, the most recently entered textbox would be either the first (tabbing backwards) or last (tabbing forwards) textbox on the page. Therefore, if the name of the current textbox matched the names I was watching for (first or last, as appropriate) than the multipage should continue to the next page (according to my previous logic). Accordingly, I made the changes shown below.

### Altered Code

Global Variable(s) added

```
Public enteredBox As String
```

Code added to each KeyDown and MouseDown event

```
enteredBox = Control.Name
```

**Edited Exit Event** with New code as shown below

```
-----------
|  New Code
-----------
```

:

```
Private Sub Multipage_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim cnt As Integer
-----------------------------------
|   Dim idWanted As Long
|   Dim temp As Integer
|   Dim endCount As Integer
-----------------------------------

    If tabDirect <> NonTab Then 'If not tabbing, skip to end of sub
        If tabDirect = Backwards Then
            counter = Multipage.Value - 1

            If counter < 0 Then
                counter = Multipage.Pages.Count - 1
            End If

            cnt = Multipage.Pages(counter).Controls.Count - 2
-------------------------------------------------------------
|           idWanted = 2
|           endCount = Multipage.Value - 1
-------------------------------------------------------------
        ElseIf tabDirect = Forwards Then
            counter = Multipage.Value + 1
            cnt = 0
-------------------------------------------------------------
|           idWanted = 1
|           endCount = Multipage.Value
-------------------------------------------------------------
        End If

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       For temp = 0 To endCount
|           idWanted = idWanted + Multipage.Pages(temp).Controls.Count / 2
|           'Division by two since each page has an associated label for each textbox
|       Next temp
|
|       'textArr is an array of textboxes on the form
|       'where textboxes were added in the order they appear on each page
|       If textArr(idWanted).Name = enteredBox Then
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

            'Only way for counter to equal Multipage.Pages.Count,
            'is if tabbing forward off of last page.
            'Desired result is to leave the multipage
            If counter <> Multipage.Pages.Count Then
                'Tabbing forwards: want first textbox, tabbing backwards: want last
                If tabDirect = Backwards Then
                    cnt = Multipage.Pages(counter).Controls.Count - 2 ' skip over label
                Else
                    cnt = 0
                End If

                Multipage.Value = counter

                With Multipage.Pages(counter).Controls(cnt)
                    .SetFocus
                    .SelStart = 0
                    .SelLength = Len(.Value)
                End With

                'Fixing scollbar
                If tabDirect = Backwards Then
                    Multipage.Pages(counter).ScrollTop = Multipage.Pages(counter).ScrollHeight
                Else
                    Multipage.Pages(counter).ScrollTop = 0
                End If

                'Don't want to cancel when leaving first page backwards
                If tabDirect <> Backwards Or counter <> Multipage.Pages.Count - 1 Then
                    Cancel = True
                End If
            Else
                Multipage.Value = 0
                Multipage.Pages(0).ScrollTop = 0
            End If
--------------------
|       End If
--------------------
    End If
End Sub
```